# ruby - File-private methods

Tags: ruby, visibility

In ruby, is there a way to define a method that is visible by every class in the file (or in the module), but not by files that require the file ?

Related, but not quite the same: can we redefine a method (for instance a method from a class of the standard library) such that this redefinition is visible only in the current file ? All other files should view the original definition.

Comment: Just wondering why do you need it? Is it realy useful in any situation?

Comment: Well, encapsulation is always a good thing. If you are writing a lib, you don't want users to start messing with the internals. Still, it might be useful to have other classes of the implementation use your private methods.

In C++ you have friend classes to do this, in Java the default visibility is "package-protected".

As for redefinitions, I mostly want to avoid namespace clashes. I might want to add some functionalities to a library class, but if everyone and their friends do this in their own libraries, chaos ensues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No and no.

The only visibilities in Ruby are public, protected, and private. There is no concept of file-level visibility. You could maybe "cheat" and and do something like this:

```
# In some file foobar.rb

class Foo
  def to_bar
    Bar.new.file_private
  end
end

class Bar
  def file_private
    raise unless caller[0].split(':')[0] == __FILE__
  end
end
```

```
# In IRB or some other file

Foo.new.to_bar  #=> nil
Bar.new.file_private  #=> RuntimeError
```

But this is a bad idea. A file of the same name in a different directory *might* work. It also isn't true visibility, but rather enforces it in the method itself.

Really, though, you should mostly have your classes each in their own file. It makes organization better. Further, you should not depend on public/protected/private. You can always just use `send` to call a private method, but the above *breaks* that expectation. If user of your code really wants to do something with your code, there's next to nothing from letting them do it, that's the nature of dynamic languages. If you don't document a method, most users will never even know it's there anyway `:P`.

As for your second question, there is no way to have two methods of the same name in the same class with different visibility, the second method will always overwrite the original. You could do something similar to what I've done above, and run different code depending on the condition instead of raising, but as above I don't really think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a new method in Object class(like an attribute). If you do not want to mess up the Object class, you can use another name, and Foo should inherit that class.

   ```
   class Object
     @@file_only_methods = []

     def file_only(method_name)
       method_name = method_name.to_sym
       new_method_name = "file_only_#{method_name}".to_sym
       self.send(:alias_method, new_method_name, method_name)
       self.send(:undef_method, method_name)
       self.send(:private, new_method_name)
       @@file_only_methods << method_name
     end


     def method_missing(method_name, *arg, &block)
       if @@file_only_methods.include? method_name
         if __FILE__ == $0
           self.send("file_only_#{method_name}".to_sym,*arg,&block)
         else
           raise "Method #{method_name} is called outside the definition file."
         end
       else
         raise "Method #{method_name} does not exist."
       end
     end
   end

   class Foo
     def bar
       puts 'bar method'
     end
     file_only :bar
   end

   Foo.new.bar
   #output:bar method
   Foo.new.x
   #output:no method
   ```

   In file2.rb,

   ```
   require_relative 'file1'
   Foo.new.bar
   #output: Method bar is called outside the definition file.
   ```

Comment: Neither of these really work since the condition is run in the context of class loading, not executing a method. Each method will either always or never be private/aliased.

Comment: @Norswap, @AndrewMarshall: First one is working without changing anything. File 1 test line: `Foo.new.bar`, output is `bar method`. File 2: `require_relative 'file1';Foo.new.bar;`, it gives error: private method called. I will test the second one tonight

Comment: But if I create another class in the same file as `Foo` with a method that calls `Foo.new.bar` I get "NoMethodError: private method `bar' called".

Comment: @AndrewMarshall How about now? I aliased the old method to a new one, undefine the old method, and masked the new method, and use `method_missing` to do the actual call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes, since ruby 2.0.

Ruby is really all about objects, not files, so you probably shouldn't do this.  In general, you should just use classes and objects to accomplish whatever it is you want.

However, ruby *does* have a mechanism to accomplish both of your questions: [refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

Unfortunately, although refinements have been in ruby for a decade, most developers still consider them experimental and esoteric.  Refinements have been changed in backwards incompatible ways several times since they were introduced.  More significantly, they can impose a significant performance penalty.  Although I have run benchmarks on some simple refinement-using code and seen little to no performance impact, refinements break ruby's internal method caches in ways that can cause *very* significant slow downs (as of ruby 3.2).  And, as far as I know, the existing JIT compilers do not even attempt to optimize refined method calls.  See https://shopify.engineering/the-case-against-monkey-patching for other reasons not to do this.  In particular, please read the "A Note on Refinements" section in that article.

Anyway, with all of those caveats and warnings put aside, here is a demonstration:

```
# refine_file_scoped_methods.rb
using(Module.new do
  refine Object do
    def hello_file! = puts "In refined file:   hello world! :)"
  end
  refine Integer do
    def + rhs
      return super unless self == 2 && rhs == 2
      5
    end
  end
end)

class Integer
  def plus_two = self + 2
end

hello_file!
puts "In refined file:   2 + 2      = #{2 + 2}"
puts "In refined file:   2.plus_two = #{2.plus_two}"
```

```rb
# unrefined.rb
require_relative "refine_file_scoped_methods"

begin
  hello_file!
rescue NoMethodError
  puts "In unrefined file: No hello...  :("
end

puts "In unrefined file: 2 + 2      = #{2 + 2}"
puts "In unrefined file: 2.plus_two = #{2.plus_two}"
```

And this is the output of `ruby -I. unrefined.rb`:

```
$ ruby -I. unrefined.rb
In refined file:   hello world! :)
In refined file:   2 + 2      = 5
In refined file:   2.plus_two = 5
In unrefined file: No hello...  :(
In unrefined file: 2 + 2      = 4
In unrefined file: 2.plus_two = 5
```