# How to give methods package-private visibility in Ruby or Python

Tags: python, ruby, visibility

Java has a visibility named [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which means that something can only be accessed inside the package it is defined in, and not outside. I'm wondering if there is any way to add this feature to Ruby (with modules) or Python.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
module Foo
  class FooClass
    def print_message_package
      # Some line to test that the last caller is in module Foo
      puts 'Hello'
    end

    def print_message_public
      print_message_package
    end
  end
end

test = Foo::FooClass.new
# I would like that following line raises an error, because it is not called inside module Foo
test.print_message_package
# This line should not raise an error:
test.print_message_public
```

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but this answer seems to show a way to do this in Ruby https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535890/2230115

Comment: It could be a nice solution, but it uses files. I have to add a lot of classes, and I should not add all of them in a single file

Comment: I will test it if I canuse this feature

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then. I'm sure you could do something similar with modules

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do this

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://blog.arkency.com/2016/02/private-classes-in-ruby/ `private_constant` would allow you to make a class private inside a module.  e.g. `module Foo; class Bar; end; private_constant :Bar;end` would cause `Foo::Bar` to raise a `NameError` if accessed from outside of the context of `Foo`

Comment: I'm looking to change the visibility of individual methods, not the entire class

Comment: You mean the `private` keyword? Eg `class Foo; private; def some_method;end;end;`? This will make `some_method` private to instances of the class `Foo` Sorry your question is a bit unclear

Comment: I'm sorry so much. I will add an example

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I was able to get this working using the `binding_of_caller` gem.
Just do `gem install binding_of_caller` and the below code should work for what you need.

Please note that this is heavily copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535890/2230115 and you should definitely upvote it :)

```
require 'binding_of_caller'
class Object
  @@module_scoped_methods = []

  def module_visibility(method_name, module_name)
    method_name = method_name.to_sym
    module_name = module_name.to_sym
    new_method_name = "module_only_#{method_name}".to_sym
    self.send(:alias_method, new_method_name, method_name)
    self.send(:undef_method, method_name)
    self.send(:private, new_method_name)
    @@module_scoped_methods << [method_name, module_name]
  end

  alias_method :old_method_missing, :method_missing
  undef_method :method_missing
  def method_missing(method_name, *arg, &block)
    method_ob = @@module_scoped_methods.find { |m| m[0] == method_name }
    if method_ob
      if binding.of_caller(1).eval('self.class').ancestors.find {|m| m.name.split('::').map{|c|c.to_sym}.include? method_ob[1]}
        self.send("module_only_#{method_name}".to_sym,*arg,&block)
      else
        raise "Method #{method_name} is called outside the set module."
      end
    else
      old_method_missing(method_name, arg, block)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
module A
  class Test
    def test
      5
    end
    #Method name, and module wanted to be scoped to.
    #Required since you can have nested modules.
    module_visibility :test, :A 
  end
  class B
    def test
      A::Test.new.test
    end
  end
end
# raises runtime error "method test is called outside the set module
A::Test.new.test
A::B.new.test # => 5
```

### How it works:

We alter the Object class to keep track of a list of methods that have been restricted to module visibility. This stores a two element array with the method name, and the module it's been scoped to. It then changes the name of the method to `module_only_<originalname>` and makes it private.

Then, so that we can call it, we override `method_missing`, so that it checks for that method in the list of methods we've assigned to module scope. It checks the ancestors of the caller's class for the module it's been scoped to. If any of the ancestors are the module it's been scoped to, it calls the method. If not, it raises an error that it's not called in the module you scoped it to.